# Fetch list of filename from mysql and add in indexed array in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named as 'files' with fields id, formID ,filename, date_modified.

Now i want to fetch list of filenames from this table to an array with index of array from each row with same formID in that array for example:

(In core php)

**Instead of this**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file_name] => filename1.jpg
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [file_name] => filename2.jpg
        )
)
```

**I want result in this format:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => filename1.jpg
    [1] => filename2.jpg
)
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: Share your code how you are fetching records from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this

```
   $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT filenames  FROM tablename");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    print_r($result);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => filename1.jpg
    [1] => filename2.jpg
)
```

Comment: Do or do not. Why should the OP "use this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Use a select query, then do a while loop to loop through each row. During that loop, assign the filename to each position of `$array`, be it what you name it.

```
$conn = $mysqli_connect(.....);


    $query = "SELECT id,formID,filename,date_modified FROM files";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $array[] = $row['filename'];
    }
    $result->close();
    $conn->close();
    print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function returns the values from a single column in the input array.

```
$result = array_column($yourArray, 'file_name');
```

Comment: Do or do not. Why should the OP "use" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. There is no function `array_collumn()`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Is it ok now?